# handler.postdelayed is not working

Tags: java, android

`handler.postdelayed` is not working, application has stopped - please help

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texte);
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            txt.setText(String.valueOf(1020));
        }
    },5000);
```

Comment: `postDelayed` **is** working - your `txt` is most likely `null` (or even `handler`)

Comment: Post your error stacktrace

Comment: `application has stopped` doesn't tell us much.

Comment: Post your logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not initializing `handler` properly. Initialize `handler` in `onCreate` method. Use this code.

```
Handler handler;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  // initialize Handler
  handler= new Handler(getMainLooper());

  txt= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texte);
  handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          txt.setText(String.valueOf(1020));
      }
  },  5000);
```

Hope this will resolve your problem. Please let me know its working or not.

Comment: Calling in an oviridized class was not working. Thank you very much.